# xquery extract expression using character position

Tags: string, substring, xquery, concatenation

I have the following XML:

```
<activity>
  <server>digmspt1p:1043SERVER1</server>
</activity>
```

I need to extract using `XQuery`, the string until the port :
`digmspt1p:1043`, this means 4th until position after `:`.

Is there a function to achieve this ?

I found only `functx:substring-before-last-match` and this helps only when the SERVER1 would not contain numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question fully?  What is the output you are looking for? Have you tried fn:substring-after?

Comment: i expect as output: "digmspt1p:1043". substring after does not work because I may have digits also in the string after the port. I need to substring until the 4th or 5th charcater after the ':' because the port may have also 5 digits

Comment: What is your exact condition to substring after 4th or 5th ? The 5th or 6th being a letter ? I think with a combination of fn:subtring-before() to keep 'digmspt1p:' and both fn:substring-after and fn:substring() for the port number using a condition for extracting till 4th or 5th char, you should be able to do the job. You may also try to build a regexp for your exact match condition.

Comment: @loky Its easy. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let $a := <activity>
                <server>digmspt1p:1043SERVER1</server>
          </activity>

  let $fir := substring-before($a/server, ":")
  let $sec := substring(substring-after($a/server, ":"),1,4)
  let $con := concat($fir, ":",$sec)

  return $con
```

The variable `$fir` will store the string before ":", in your case it will be 'digmspt1p'.

`$sec` will first get the string after the ":", and then using `substring()` it will cut the first 4 characters as required.

Lastly, the `$con` will concat both the variable to get the required output.

HTH.

Comment: @loky - If the answer helped you please accept it as answer.